# Ninja Forms - Align text area and submit button

Tags: forms, wordpress, ninja-forms

I just put a simple email subscription form on my website using Ninja Forms Wordpress plugin. The submit button is under the text area. How to I make the submit button align to the right of the text area?

```
<div class="email-form-wrap">

<?php if( function_exists( 'ninja_forms_display_form' ) ){ ninja_forms_display_form( 22 ); } ?>

</div>
```

The class for the textarea is 'email-text-area'

The class for the submit button is 'email-sub'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to specify some classes to your fields - http://prntscr.com/bdalyh
Then add some styles to it:

```
.subscribe__email-wrap{
  float:left;
  width:calc(100% - 100px);
}

.subscribe__submit-wrap{
  float:right;
  width:100px;
}
```

note that you should add `-wrap` in the end to style field contaienr and not field directly. 
In the end you need to add some clearfix styles to you form:

```
.ninja-forms-all-fields-wrap:after{
  content:'';
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Worked great. Thank you.